# Can't find Bing spell check errors in LUIS

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding, bing

Bing Spell Check is not working in LUIS, and LUIS does not show an error message.

I'm trying to use Bing Spell Check in LUIS (online - luis.ai), but it is not working, and LUIS does not show an error message. I can call the spell check API directly with our subscription key and it works fine. I can mangle the sub's key and it shows an error, so I know spell check itself is working fine.

It does not work when called from the LUIS testing panel. I have tried valid and invalid keys, but nothing is shown in LUIS. How do I see the error(s)? Where does LUIS post those error messages?

Comment: Please post the answer if you found it

Comment: Chandra - I gave up on this problem, I don't know of a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can test on luis.ai by including your Bing Spell Check subscription key as a session variable in the testing panel. Following these steps should get you the results you are looking for.

1. Open the Test panel and enter a misspelled word (e.g. "greating" instead of "greeting".

[image]

2. Once entered, click the "Inspect" link
3. Click "Compare with published"

[image]

4. Click the "Additional Settings" link and choose your the endpoint to test against

[image]

5. Check the Enable Bing Spell Check option, enter your subscription key in the input field, and click Done

[image]

6. Click the "Show JSON view" link to view the response, including the "alteredQuery" value housing the corrected spelling

[image]
[image]

Hope of help!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is not what I meant but your screen shots will help the discussion.   What do you see if you alter your subscription key so it is intentionally wrong?  This is where I did not see an error message.  Actually in our case we had exceeded our quota, but there was no indication that anything was wrong, the spell check simply did not work.

Comment: It has been 21 days since I asked this question and no answer yet, so I am concluding that LUIS does **not** display errors anywhere.